# How can I get all the routes (from all the modules and controllers available on each module) in Nestjs?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

Using Nestjs I'd like to get a list of all the available routes (controller methods) with http verbs, like this:

```
API:
      POST   /api/v1/user
      GET    /api/v1/user
      PUT    /api/v1/user
```

It seems that access to express router is required, but I haven found a way to do this in Nestjs. For express there are some libraries like "[express-list-routes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-list-routes)" or "[express-list-endpoints](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-list-endpoints)".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see this link, its gitHub `express-list-routes` and `index.js` file. look at this and re-write this code for yourself : https://github.com/labithiotis/express-list-routes/blob/master/index.js. All it takes is a few lines of code

Comment: @mohammadjavadahmadi The problem is that I don't know wether there's a way to access the "route stack" (I see that's what the "express-list-routes" receives).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just found that Nestjs app has a "getHttpServer()" method, with this I was able to access the "router stack", here's the solution:

```
// main.ts

import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as expressListRoutes from 'express-list-routes';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(3000);


  const server = app.getHttpServer();
  const router = server._events.request._router;
  console.log(expressListRoutes({}, 'API:', router));

}
bootstrap();
```

[image: Nestjs available routes!]

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated, I installed `express-list-routes` and followed the same steps, it doesn't work. Using `console.log('API:', server._events.request);`, I get `[Function]`. Are you still using the same method?

Comment: It works with Nestjs, without any other package. Are you using express directly instead of Nestjs? That could be the reason why it's not working. @Adham Sabry

Comment: @mr-d-mx I am using express afaik, what do you mean by are you suing express directly instead of nestjs?

Also, 
```
 await app.listen(3000);
  const server = app.getHttpServer(); // is this line reachable with the await above?
  const router = server._events.request._router;
  console.log(expressListRoutes({}, 'API:', router));
```

Comment: @mr-d-mx:
```
console.log(router, expressListRoutes);
  console.log(expressListRoutes({}, 'API:', router));
```
I get the following:
```
undefined { default: [Function] }
(node:5006) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: expressListRoutes is not a function
    at bootstrap (main.js:44:17)
```

Comment: i am using the default nestjs server which i assume express by default.

Comment: Is this specific to express? If so is there an equivalent command for fastify?

Answer (score 33):

main.ts

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
  const server = app.getHttpServer();
  const router = server._events.request._router;

  const availableRoutes: [] = router.stack
    .map(layer => {
      if (layer.route) {
        return {
          route: {
            path: layer.route?.path,
            method: layer.route?.stack[0].method,
          },
        };
      }
    })
    .filter(item => item !== undefined);
  console.log(availableRoutes);
}
bootstrap();
```

Comment: This works great but is it possible to get the Guards information with every endpoint?

Answer (score 9):

```
import { Controller, Get, Request } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Request as ExpressRequest, Router } from "express";

...

@Get()
root(@Request() req: ExpressRequest) {
    const router = req.app._router as Router;
    return {
        routes: router.stack
            .map(layer => {
                if(layer.route) {
                    const path = layer.route?.path;
                    const method = layer.route?.stack[0].method;
                    return `${method.toUpperCase()} ${path}`
                }
            })
            .filter(item => item !== undefined)
    }
}

...
```

```json
{
    "routes": [
        "GET /",
        "GET /users",
        "POST /users",
        "GET /users/:id",
        "PUT /users/:id",
        "DELETE /users/:id",
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Nest every native server is [wrapped](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/http-adapter) in an adapter. For those, who use `Fastify`:

```
// main.ts

app
    .getHttpAdapter()
    .getInstance()
    .addHook('onRoute', opts => {
      console.log(opts.url)
    })
```

More about fastify hooks [here](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/master/docs/Hooks.md#application-hooks).

Comment: `addHook` doesn't exist on `getInstance()`

Comment: I use Fastify, the code above works, even though you don't get code completion for the instance. However, you need to place it before the app.listen() statement because the hooks are triggered when the routes are added to the app.

Answer (score -1):

It works perfectly:

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as expressListRoutes from 'express-list-routes';

async function getApp() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  await app.listen(3000);

  expressListRoutes(app.getHttpServer()._events.request._router);

  return app;
}

getApp();
```

Output:

```
[Nest] 11619  - 10/03/2022 19:53:56     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +3ms
GET      /ui
GET      /ui-json
GET      /
GET      /api/v1/auth
```