# Unit Testing the NestJS Routes are defined

Tags: testing, routes, jestjs, nestjs

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58255000/how-can-i-get-all-the-routes-from-all-the-modules-and-controllers-available-on) about determine the routes.  While the first answer is exactly what I need, and it works

```
import { Controller, Get, Request } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Request as ExpressRequest, Router } from "express";

@Get()
root(@Request() req: ExpressRequest) {
    const router = req.app._router as Router;
    return {
        routes: router.stack
            .map(layer => {
                if(layer.route) {
                    const path = layer.route?.path;
                    const method = layer.route?.stack[0].method;
                    return `${method.toUpperCase()} ${path}`
                }
            })
            .filter(item => item !== undefined)
    }
}
```

I want to be able to unit test this.

My end to end test works fine

```
    it('/api (GET) test expected routes', async done => {
        const ResponseData = await request(app.getHttpServer())
            .get('/api')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json');

        expect(ResponseData.status).toBe(200);
        expect(ResponseData.headers['content-type']).toContain('json');
        expect(ResponseData.body.routes.length).toBeGreaterThan(2);
        done();         // Call this to finish the test
    });
```

The problem I am having, is how to create and pass the Request part that is needed for the root() call for a unit test.  The ExpressRequest is not a class or anything to simply create, and then assign values.  It is currently a large definition.  I assume there must be an easy way to create one, but I have not found it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the [`@golevelup/ts-jest`](https://github.com/golevelup/nestjs/tree/master/packages/testing) package to help create mocks of objects. It can take an interface as a generic and return an entire jest mock that is compatible with the type.

Comment: That looks promising, but I was looking to be able to test that the routes that I have defined in the code, are available.  For instance, the code is returning the endpoints with HTTP verbs  ('GET /api', 'GET /healthz', etc...). With this mock, I would loose that, unless I tried to create the deeper structure that is getting parsed.  Part of what I am trying to test, is that this structure returned does not change, as other things are using it, and I know of the 2 basic paths (above) that will always be present so I can test they are there in the proper format.

Comment: Not sure why there is a down vote, as I did not do it, and do not see any comments to indicate it.  Your mock idea would work for creating the object to test. I just need to be able to have it work more without a mock to test that it still works.  I will people would add comments when down voting.

Comment: People will down vote what they want. It sounds like you're wanting to do more than just unit test the functionality, which would mean that a mock would be less than ideal, though it looks like you have a proper e2e test set up. The library I linked is great for easily creating mocks and assigning values to that mock, and can go deep down the object tree to assign values, which is why I figured it would be useful here.